# Saving variables in applescript using plist's within application xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, nsapplescript

How do I make my script write to a Property List file without having to create a ".plist" file on the user's computer, but rather directly in the current application?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like an "in memory" PLIST file which is never written to disk? Or are you after something else? And why would you want to use a PLIST file specifically if you are looking for a an "in memory" collection of information since then you are probably looking for an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @Fahim I am trying to save simple variables such as short strings and some booleans.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, is there a specific reason for using the PLIST format? If you are not writing the file to disk, can't you use an `NSDictionary` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plist files are created from the user defaults. So you need to save your values there.

Make a property to shorten writings at top

```
property NSUserDefaults : class "NSUserDefaults" of current application
```

to write

```
NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s setObject_forKey_(yourValue, yourKey)
```

to read

```
NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s object_forKey(yourKey)
```

Example

```
property NSUserDefaults : class "NSUserDefaults" of current application

set mytext to "Hello"

-- write
NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s setObject_forKey_(mytext, "MyKey")

-- read it with
log NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s object_forKey_("MyKey")
-- Hello
```

It's untested cause i don't have a mac here at the moment. But it should work.

**Edit**

To set standard values do the following in your application's appDelegate method applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification (don't forget to declare the property mentioned above):

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification
    set prefs to {MyKey:"Hello", SomeOtherKey:true}
    NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s registerDefaults_(prefs)
end
```

Comment: How to I create a changeable default set to a boolean, and write to that? I don't have any experience with "log", but how do I set a global variable to whatever I previously set as a "user default"?

Comment: Updated the answer. And with log you can output values to your console. Log works for ASOC projects while for pure OBJC projects you only can use NSLog. If you don't know log you should spend some time with debugging

Comment: can I use this code to set my variable within the script to a user default? like this: `set theVariable to NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s object_forKey_("MyKey")`

Comment: Can I do this in my script: `set theVariable to NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults()'s object_forKey_("MyKey")`

Comment: Yes. Remove one underscore. Why do you ask and not just try it?

Comment: I will, but why remove one underscore?

Comment: -.- if you would just try... you'd see it fails. This method has one parameter. One parameter, one underscore. object_forKey ("MyKey"). I explained that to you in another question already.